# mocha IT inside of a callback

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am new to mocha and node.

I am trying to write some tests using mocha that check a variety of properties of an SSL cert. I have a function `getCert` which opens a tls socket.

However, I can't find a way to call the function once and perform multiple mocha tests on the callback from `getCert`.

Is it possible to do this? Here is my code...

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var tls = require('tls');
const moment = require('moment');

var hostToTest = 'www.google.com';

//this is based a little on https://www.npmjs.com/package/certificate-monitor
function getCert(host, port, callback) {
  let socketOptions = { 
    host: host, 
    port: port, 
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false,
    authorized: null,
    cert: null,
    error: null,
    daysRemaining: null
  };

  const socket = tls.connect(socketOptions, function() {
    socketOptions.authorized = socket.authorized;
    socketOptions.cert = socket.getPeerCertificate(true);
    var expireDate = new Date(socketOptions.cert.valid_to).toJSON();
    socketOptions.daysRemaining = moment(expireDate, moment.ISO_8601).diff(moment(), 'days');
    socket.end();
    callback(socketOptions);
  });

  socket.on('error', function (err){
    socketOptions.error = err;
    callback(socketOptions);
  });
}

//This works, but I have to call getCert multiple times
describe('TLS Certificate Checks 1', function() {
    it('Certificate should be trusted', function(done) {
        getCert(hostToTest, 443, function(certResponse){ 
            assert.isTrue(certResponse.authorized);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('Certificate should not be close to expirey', function(done) {
        getCert(hostToTest, 443, function(certResponse){ 
            assert.isAbove(certResponse.daysRemaining, 30);
            done();
        });
    });
});

//this does nothing... is it possible to call getcert just once?
describe('TLS Certificate Checks 2', function() {
  getCert(hostToTest, 443, function(certResponse){ 
    it('Certificate should be trusted', function(done) {
      assert.isTrue(certResponse.authorized);
      done();
    });

    it('Certificate should not be close to expirey', function(done) {
      assert.isBelow(certResponse.daysRemaining, 30);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the output from the above code:

```
$mocha testssl.js 


  TLS Certificate Checks 1
    ✓ Certificate should be trusted (56ms)
    ✓ Certificate should not be close to expirey


  2 passing (100ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called "Hooks" in Mocha. You can call the getCert method before each test is ran.

```
describe('TLS Certificate Checks 2', function() {
  var certResponse = null;

  // THIS IS A HOOK
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    certResponse = null;

    // runs before each test in this block
    getCert(hostToTest, 443, function(result){
      certResponse = result;
      done();
    });
  });

  // PUT TEST CASES HERE
  it('Certificate should be trusted', function(done) {
    assert.isTrue(certResponse.authorized);
    done();
  });

  it('Certificate should not be close to expirey', function(done) {
    assert.isBelow(certResponse.daysRemaining, 30);
    done();
  });

});
```

beforeEach will run before each test.

Comment: perfect! THanks very much :)